# 'Permission denied: Missing or insufficient permissions.'

Tags: ios, firebase, uikit, firebase-storage

I'm a newbie over coding. I have a struggle to upload docs to Firestore Database while writing code in SwiftUIKit. The program gives me alert message as

**'Permission denied: Missing or insufficient permissions.'/ failed: Missing or insufficient permissions**

I've checked the message and tried all solutions, but still couldn't fix it. I've changed the rules in Firebase lots of time the last one is like;

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null
    
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my code, the app supposed to be run/upload the data to the Database, but it is not. I hope that you can help me... thank youuuu :)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class UploadViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var yorumTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gorselSec))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    @objc func gorselSec() {
        
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 
        
        }
        
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        imageView.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
   
    
    
    @IBAction func yukleTiklandi(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageReference = storage.reference()
        let mediaFolder = storageReference.child("media")
        if let data = imageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5){
            let uuid = UUID().uuidString
            let imageReference = mediaFolder.child("\(uuid).jpg")
            imageReference.putData(data) { storagemetadata, error in
                if error != nil {
                    self.hataMesajiGoster(title: "Hata", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Hata Aldınız, tekrar deneyin.")
                } else {
                    imageReference.downloadURL { [self] url, error in
                        if error == nil {
                            let imageUrl = url?.absoluteString
                            if let imageUrl = imageUrl {
                                let firestoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()
                                let firestorePost = ["gorselurl": imageUrl, "yorum" : yorumTextField.text!, "email" : Auth.auth().currentUser?.email, "tarih" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()]
                                
                                firestoreDatabase.collection("Post").addDocument(data: firestorePost) { (error) in
                                    
                                    if error != nil {
                                        self.hataMesajiGoster(title: "Hata", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Hata Aldınız, Tekrar Deneyiniz!")
                                    } else {
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func hataMesajiGoster(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okayButton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't code for Swift, but I think I can help you solve this problem.

From your code it looks like you are dealing with firebase storage and not firestore. I recommend that you use the following rule to test locally:

`allow read, write: if true`

With this, you can test even if you don't have a user logged in.

If you want to continue with your rule, I suggest that at the code level, you check if the user is logged in.
As I don't know much about swift, I'll give you the link to the documentation where you can find the syntax.

[Get the currently signed-in user - Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users)